# How to add Tooltip on macOS 10.15 with SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

According to Apple `help` modifier is only available in macOS11, so what is the workaround for adding a tooltip in macOS 10.15?

> In SwiftUI on macOS 11, you can use the .help("Tooltip text") view modifier to add a tooltip. See the "What's new in SwiftUI" session for WWDC 2020.

**REFERENCE**

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123243

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround is to use a overplayed old `NSView`
import SwiftUI

```
struct Tooltip: NSViewRepresentable {
    let tooltip: String
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Tooltip>) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        view.toolTip = tooltip

        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<Tooltip>) {
    }
}

public extension View {
    func toolTip(_ toolTip: String) -> some View {
        self.overlay(Tooltip(tooltip: toolTip))
    }
}
```

To use the modifier

```
            Image("pin")
                .resizable()
                .toolTip("TEST")
```

[image]

Also an open-source solution can be found on GitHub, https://github.com/quassummanus/SwiftUI-Tooltip

Comment: This works nicely - in some cases I found I needed to add `.allowsHitTesting(false)` after `Tooltip(tooltip: toolTip)` otherwise my `Toggle`s were not receiving clicks

Comment: I just encounter this and it works a treat.  I've modified it take a closure to provide a dynamic tip.  Happy to post if anyone else stuck in 10.15 world is interested.  I was also getting my head around view modifiers.  So I have wrapped that whole thing in a view modifier.  It does not seem to add a great deal to original functionality. From those with more knowledge is there any substantive benefit from wrapping this up as a ViewModifier ?